# Ext.button's click event is not response with Bryntum Siesta Test

Tags: testing, extjs, click, sencha-cmd, siesta

I'm try to fill a `textfield` and then run **click event** with Bryntum Siesta Test. Whole test-process has been succeed but only the **'Save'** button is not response for this click event and keeps says:

```
Waited too long for: componentQuery "datatoolbar[id=datatoolbar-1100]"
Failed assertion `waitForComponentQuery` 
Condition was not fullfilled during 10000ms
```

How can I run click event for visible button with Bryntum Siesta?

**Test.js**

```
describe('Testing Update Process', function (t) {
    t.it('Should to login with correct creds.', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {waitForCQ: 'window[title=Login]'},
            {click: '>> textfield[itemId=userName]'},
            {type: 'user@name.com', target:'>> textfield[itemId=userName]'},
            {click: '>> textfield[name=password]'},
            {type: 'superSecretPass', target:'>> textfield[name=password]'},
            {click: '>> button[text=Submit]', desc: 'Submit process is succeed!'}
        )
    })

    t.it('Login window should be invisible', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {waitForCQNotVisible: 'window[title=Login]', desc: 'Login window is hidden now!'}
        )
    })

    t.it('Should open Folio grid', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {waitForCQ: 'treelist[itemId=navigationTreeList]', desc: 'Wait for treelist'},
            {click: '>> treelistitem[id=ext-treelistitem-6]', desc: 'Clicks Folio item'},
            {waitForCQ: 'treelistitem[id=ext-treelistitem-7]', desc: 'Wait for treelist sub-item: Folios'},
            {click: '>> treelistitem[id=ext-treelistitem-7]', desc: 'Clicks Folios'}
        )
    })

    t.it('Should click on Edit button', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {waitForCQ: 'gridview[id=gridview-1067]'},
            {click: '>> button[id=button-1087]', desc: 'Clicks on Edit button'}
        )
    })

    t.it('Should update Client Name', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {click: '>> textfield[name=clientname]'},
            {type: 'Siesta Testing for Update', target: '>> textfield[name=clientname]', desc: 'Types lorem ipsum data'}
        )
    })

    //This last part is giving error and test becomes failure.
    t.it('Should Save the last changes', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {waitForCQ: 'datatoolbar[id=datatoolbar-1100]'},
            {click: '>> button[id=button-1104]', desc: 'Clicks on Save, All Succeed :-)'}
        )
    })
})
```

Here is a screenshot of dataform and test snippet. As you will notice above, I've used `waitForCQ` for `datatoolbar` which is wrapped the **Save** button. Also I've tried call click event byself but it gaves error as well: `Wait for button[id=button-1104] to appear` and being failure.

The button is already visiable and wrapped DOM elements are formdata (includes labels and textfields) and datatoolbar (includes buttons).

[image]

Comment: You should not rely on auto-generated ids in your tests, because they can change easily.

Comment: Thanks for indicate @Alexander. I'll refactor queries in a solid way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, the cause is probably just an unstable query (since it uses auto-generated ids).

The error message

`Waited too long for: componentQuery "datatoolbar[id=datatoolbar-1100]"`

indicates that Siesta was running the specified component query but no results were returned for it.

Instead of auto-generated ids, try to use more stable and specific attribute of the toolbar you are targeting: `datatoolbar[specificAttr=value]`

Comment: Dear @SamuraiJack somehow that id property still stays as same --button-1104 but as you mentioned, I've used another specific property and now it works. Thanks a lot.